# Docker volume data not persisting in local

Tags: docker

I'm building a Dockerfile and files in the container are not getting synced with local storage.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8

ENV HOME=\wc_console

RUN mkdir $HOME

ADD . $HOME

WORKDIR $HOME

RUN mvn clean install -T 2C -DskipTests=true

RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B --fail-never

CMD mvn clean install -T 2C -DskipTests=true
```

My `docker build` command:

```
docker build -f build_maven_docker . -t wc_console_build:1.0
```

I want to use `bind-mount` because after the container runs, I need the output on my local directory.

My `docker run` command:

```
docker run -v e:\svn\daffodil-dev-3.4.1\whitecoats-admin:\wc_console wc_console_build:1.0
```

My current working directory in the local machine while running docker is:`e:\svn\daffodil-dev-3.4.1\whitecoats-admin`

My work directory in the Docker container:`wc_console`

But, whenever I run the docker container, it is not syncing the final output to my local directory back.

What am I doing wrong?

Image for folder visulization.
[image]

Comment: Resetting Docker password and Update docker helped me fix the volume issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `\wc_console` in your Dockerfile's `ENV HOME=\wc_console`, use `/wc_console`. Linux uses forward slashes for directory structuring. The same goes for your `docker run` command. Change

`docker run -v e:\svn\daffodil-dev-3.4.1\whitecoats-admin:\wc_console wc_console_build:1.0`

to

`docker run -v e:\svn\daffodil-dev-3.4.1\whitecoats-admin:/wc_console wc_console_build:1.0`

Comment: That is indeed an issue, but it doesn't solve the problem as all.

Comment: @Mihai Why doesn't it?

Comment: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/wc_console). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.

Comment: i get this error, i guess the change the slash is not helping.

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar: What's the location of your POM file?

Comment: wc_console is the location

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar: Is the source code public? I'd like to try it once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198169/discussion-between-sriram-arvind-lakshmanakumar-and-7-r3x).

Comment: But in addition to what you have answered, please do note, the volume issue was not solved by your answer.i had to re-set my docker password and reshare local volume in docker desktop to fix the issue.

Answer (score -2):

When you mount the volume you actually replace the contents of the /wc_console with whatever you have on your host.

If you want to get the artefacts generated by maven then you need to run the maven commands on the running container, not as part of the build process.

When you do this you also don't need to add your sources to the image at build time.

```sh
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8

ENV HOME=/wc_console

WORKDIR $HOME

# Make this part of the ENTRYPOINT if you really need it
#RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B --fail-never

ENTRYPOINT mvn clean install -T 2C -DskipTests=true
```

That being said, for what you need you don't even really need a Dockerfile:

```sh
docker run --rm -v e:\svn\daffodil-dev-3.4.1\whitecoats-admin:/wc_console --workdir /wc_console maven:3.6.1-jdk-8 mvn clean install -T 2C -DskipTests=true
```